# Primefaces 5.2, when menuitem should be evaluated/executed?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, exec, refresh, menuitem

I am using JSF 2.2 with Primefaces 5.2 to implement my JSF project. I'm trying put a linkage with menuitem by using outcome to access my backing bean controller in my main.xhtml such as:

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="headerForm">
  ......
  <p:menubar >
    <p:submenu label="#{apps['application.staff.myinfo']}" icon="ui-icon-document">
        <p:menuitem value="#{apps['application.staff.myinfo']}" immediate="true" outcome="#{staffControlBean.viewStaff()}" process="@form" update="@all" icon="fa fa-fw fa-leaf"
                    disabled="#{empty loginControlBean.staffSession.username}"/>
        <p:separator />
        <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="#" />
    </p:submenu>
  </p:menubar>
  ......
</h:form>
```

My backing bean as:

```
@Named(value = "staffControlBean")
@SessionScoped
public class StaffControlBean implements Serializable{
  private static final String STAFF_VIEW="/staff/staffView.xhtml";
  ......
  public String viewStaff(){
    logger.info("View staff from menuitem clicked.");
    if(loginControlBean.getStaffSession().isChangePassword()){
        logger.info("password has to be changed before use this services.");
        loginControlBean.fireChangePasswordDialog();
        return "";
    }else {
        return STAFF_VIEW;
    }
  }
  ......
}
```

From above snippet you will see, I expect when I click the menuitem from the menubar, backing end controller method viewStaff will be invoked to return a change password dialog or return to my staff view.

But unfortunately, **every time when I access (or refresh) main.xhtml without click any menuitem from menubar, the backing bean method was evaluated/executed twice.** This is what I found from my server log:

```
......
####<Nov 10, 2016 2:02:29 PM AEDT> <Info> <com.longz.ozssc.web.staff.StaffControlBean> <macmini16g.tweedheadstorage.com.au> <OzsscWEBServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <bc92beef-9f93-4923-a503-9a9cee37010d-00000071> <1478746949108> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000000> <View staff from menuitem clicked.> 
####<Nov 10, 2016 2:02:29 PM AEDT> <Info> <com.longz.ozssc.web.staff.StaffControlBean> <macmini16g.tweedheadstorage.com.au> <OzsscWEBServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <bc92beef-9f93-4923-a503-9a9cee37010d-00000071> <1478746949109> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000000> <View staff from menuitem clicked.>    
......
```

My question is: When the linkage or buttons in the JSF will be evaluated or executed? Why it always been evaluated or executed when the page was loaded or refreshed. How I can avoid it happen?

Any advice are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Executed twice or just logged twice?

Comment: And don't use prependId=false. Search stackoverflow on why

Comment: I removed prependId=false and restart services, there is nothing change, backing bean method is still fired twice when I load the page.

Comment: so not just duplicate logging? debug the http requests. Are there two too?

Comment: I changed the backing bean listener to action and try again, it works now. Thank you any way!